# @Autowired возвращает null

Tags: java, spring

```
@Controller
public class AuthorizationServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Autowired
private MapFormGet mapFormGet;

@Autowired
private MapFormPost mapFormPost;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
    mapFormPost.postMap.get(req.getParameter("form")).execute(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
    mapFormGet.getMap.get(req.getRequestURI()).execute(req, resp);
}
}

@Component
public class MapFormGet {

@Autowired
private AuthorizationGet authorizationGet;

@Autowired
private AdminPageUserGet adminPageUserGet;

@Autowired
private AdminPageEditGet adminPageEditGet;

@Autowired
private AdminPageAddGet adminPageAddGet;

@Autowired
private AdminPageGet adminPageGet;

@Autowired
private UserPageGet userPageGet;

@Autowired
public Map<String, Command> getMap;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    getMap.put("/system/login",authorizationGet);
    getMap.put("/system/admin/user", adminPageUserGet);
    getMap.put("system/admin/editAdmin",adminPageEditGet);
    getMap.put("system/admin/addAdmin",adminPageAddGet);
    getMap.put("system/admin",adminPageGet);
    getMap.put("system/user",userPageGet);
}

}

@Component
public class AuthorizationGet implements Command {

@Override
public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
IOException {
    String url = req.getRequestURI().split("/")[2];
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    if (url.equals("login")) {
        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("authorization") != null) {
            if (session.getAttribute("role").equals("admin")) {
                resp.sendRedirect("admin");
            } else {
                resp.sendRedirect("user");
            }
        } else {
            try {
                req.setAttribute("title", "Вход");
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB- 
 INF/jsp/login.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }
 }



 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.goodsoft.system.*">
</context:component-scan>

 </beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<display-name>Hello Spring MVC</display-name>

<!--<context-param>-->
    <!--<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>-->
    <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/springConfig.xml</param-value>-->
<!--</context-param>-->

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet- 
class>com.goodsoft.system.web.controller.AuthorizationServlet</servlet- 
class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинки кодом как текст.

Comment: Уберите свои скриншоты и приведите сам код. А пока минус

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хрустальный шар говорит мне, что вы не понимаете разницы между сервлетом и контроллером Spring MVC. Объект вашего сервлета создаётся web-контейнером, а аннотация `@Autowired` работает только для объектов созданных контейнером Spring.